# Carbon chains isomers, why is 1-methyl-hexane not a thing?

Tags: carbon-family

As title reads, why shouldn't 1-methyl-hexane work but 2-methyl-hexane and 3-methyl-hexane does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to always number your longest chain first. If you draw 1-methylhexane, you'll see the longest chain isn't actually 6 carbons anymore, but 7. Then all the atoms are part of the longest chain, and the name simply becomes heptane.